# regex match numbers after specified word and colon until other characters

Tags: regex, autohotkey

```
A : 10 | B: 2
C: 95 | D: 48
```

I'm writing a program that needs to extract numbers by its key (A, B, C, D) from a string. For example, `query_string("A")` will return `10` from the string. Right now I have come up with this regex pattern but it's only matching the first key A.

```
(?<=A)*(?<=:)*\d[^\s]
```

This is the code about what I'm basically trying to do, as requested by @WiktorStribiżew

```
/*
clipboard =
(
A : 10 | B: 2
C: 95 | D: 48
)
*/

keys := ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
empty := []

query_string(str, key) {
    RegExMatch(str, "O)\b" key "\s*:\s*(\d+)", output)
    return output[1]
}

F1::
for index, key in keys {
    if (query_string(clipboard, key) > 1) {
        send % key
    } else {
        empty.Push(key)
    }
}
return
```

Comment: Just use capturing groups, `\bA\s*:\s*(\d+)`. What is the programming language? Is the space or end of string required after a number?

Comment: I suspect you need help with dynamic regex building, if yes, please add the code to the question.

Comment: `([a-zA-Z]+)\s*:\s*(\d+)` matches key as group 1, digit as group 2. See [regex demo](https://regexr.com/5h363)

Comment: The pattern has 3 matches https://regex101.com/r/41bjlT/1 but will also match only 10 as the lookbehinds are optionally repeated. It does not match 2 because `\d[^\s]` expects 2 characters, 1 digit and 1 non whitespace char. You could match uppercase chars ABCD and the digits using 2 capturing groups. `([A-D])\s*:\s*(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/txZB0L/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird OP write the code that "*needs to extract numbers by its key*". That is why I think `[A-D]` is not what they need. This is an off-topic question for the time being.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes dynamic regex building, that's what I was trying to do. Just learned something new, thanks!

Comment: `pcre` is not a language, it is a regex library. What is your programming language.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's AutoHotkey, I thought programming language is negligible since regex is common in all languages, but if you have any solutions other than regex I will be glad to see that!

Comment: Regex is not common. Each regex library is quite specific. Try `[\s-[\r\n]]` in AHK and C#. `\d` in `sed` / `bash` and in JavaScript. `[^\W\d]` in PostgreSQL and JavaScript. 
 `[:alpha:]+` in R *stringr::str_replace* and in R `sub`. Please add your current code to the question to see where you have a problem.

Comment: Please add your current code to the question to see where you have a problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok I have added the code to illustrate the problem

Comment: So what is the current behavior? Where is the problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It wasn't matching correctly with the previous regex I wrote. But now it's fixed with your regex pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
query_string(str, key) {
    RegExMatch(str, "O)\b" key "\s*:\s*(\d+)", output)
    return output[1]
```

The regex will look like `\bA\s*:\s*(\d+)` and will match:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `A` - the key you will pass to the method
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - **Group 1**: any one or more digits.

The `O)` inline options [tells AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm) to output the match results as *OutputVar* variable so that you could grab the required value from `output[1]`:

> If a capital `O` is present in the RegEx's options -- such as `"O)abc.*123"` -- a [match object](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm#MatchObject) is stored in *OutputVar*. This object can be used to retrieve the position, length and value of the overall match and of each [captured subpattern](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm#subpat), if present.

Answer (score 0):

You can do This:

```
query_string(key, text):
    import re
    result = re.findall('(?:(?:' + key  + ')\s*:\s*)([0-9]*\s)', text)
    return result
```

This will return the value for the given key and you have to do this for all the key you want to extract the value

[Regex demo](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A(%3F%3AA)%5Cs*%3A%5Cs*)(%5B0-9%5D*%5Cs)&test_string=A%20%3A%2010%20%7C%20B%3A%202%0AC%3A%2095%20%7C%20D%3A%2048&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: @skygate I am sure you [don't want this](https://regex101.com/r/YIur9B/1).

Comment: it's a probem with your site becouse [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A(%3F%3AA)%5Cs*%3A%5Cs*)(%5B0-9%5D*%5Cs)&test_string=A%20%3A%2010%20%7C%20B%3A%202%0AC%3A%2095%20%7C%20D%3A%2048&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) it works